# WorldPay integration

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, payment-gateway, worldpay

I am currently working a system whereby my users can pay for items that they have added to an order.

The payment will be using Worldpay.

I have a Worldpay account, but I am a little confused as to what steps I need to do next.

I am using symfony and I have an order, with products associated to it. I have then created a 'Pay Now' link, which links to a `executePayment` action.

What I'd really like, is for this to then take me to the hosted payment pages on Worldpay, pay for the order and then takes me back to my site to an `order success` page.

Has anyone implemented WorldPay using symfony before?

Thanks

EDIT:

So It seems, that I can have a form on the page where the `Pay Now` button is, but change it to a `<input type="submit" />` and then post the details to `https://secure-test.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/wcc/purchase`

Is there some kind of callback functioanlity, to redirect me to a confirmation/failure page if the transaction was completed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I user RBSWorldPay with Symfony - its very simple to setup - yes there is a callback function that you setup within the Settings of your RBSWorldPay account - you can also test by adding a test field - again check the RBS Documentation for testing.

Answer (score 1):

WorldPay works like this...

1) You have a form on your website that collects your customer details. You then POST this data to https://secure-test.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/wcc/purchase

2) The customer will add their payment details in to WorldPay

3) Next, (depending on if the payment was successful or not) the user will be either directed to your resultY.html or resultC.html page that you can upload to your file management section within the WorldPay admin.

Alternatively you can supply a URL to a callback file on your server that is pinged when the customer clicks pay. This allows you to get information about the transaction and add it to your database.

With the callback page on your server, you can output a confirmation of payment, but you then have to include a link to physically get the user to come back to your site. I think automatically redirecting from this page is against Worldpay's T&Cs.

Hope this helps.

Philip